# Como parar um loop for que armazena os valores de strings digitados no C++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, loop, for, c++11

Então eu já tentei de tudo tentei comparar tipo digitou um "." ou definir um valor limite e mesmo assim o programa não continua, ele fica dentro do loop infinito.
O código vem a seguir:

```
vector<string> inserir(){
    vector<string>f;
        for(int x = 0;x < 5;x++){
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        f.push_back(s);
    }
    return f;
}
```

alguém pode me ajudar? Alguém que já obteve o mesmo problema?

Comment: Só pra entender seu código está preso no for(... ?
Estranho por que ele deveria fazer o loop 5 vezes como você definiu.
Verifica se é ali mesmo que ele ta travando.

Comment: so pode ser ai porque ele dps de digitar 5 palavras ele continua no cin esperando pra digitar mais

Comment: Percebi agora que vc está usando cin>>s; e o programa vai parar nessa linha aguardando vc entrar algum dado com o teclado e aguardar o Enter pra prosseguir.

Comment: eu uso eclipse, não descartei a possibilidade de ser ele fazendo graça

Comment: tentei em outra ide deu a mesma coisa...

Comment: use std::getline(std::cin, s) ao invés de cin >> s.

Comment: então quando eu quiser ler uma string eu uso getline()?

Comment: coloque um exemplo (pequeno) completo...o código que você postou não parece ter erros

Comment: http://cpp.sh/9x2n3 postei c++ shell pra facilitar

Answer (score 1):

Seu código em http://cpp.sh/9x2n3 possui uma linha assim

```
for (int y = 0; y < med.size(); x++) {
```

Essa linha se repete indefinidamente. Correção óbvia:

```
for (int y = 0; y < med.size(); y++) {
```

Comment: Não entendi o que você quis dizer

Comment: você está y para controlar o loop, mas está incrementando x...o valor de y vai continuar sendo zero, e a condição de saída do loop nunca vai ocorrer...mais do que isso não sei como explicar

Comment: Entendi, obrigado